# Psycopg2 execute tuple index out of range

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am very new to python and this is my first programming language. This is my first shot at using SQL as well as psycopg2. Any "dumb" advice is much appreciated!

I am not sure what the problem is. My research tells me im feeding too few or too many arguments to the `cursor.execute(INSERT...` but i have tried a number of different counts and can't seem to get any working correctly. From my point of view the `cursor.execute(CREATE...` creates a table with 6 columns and i am passing 6 args to it.

```
from lxml import html  # Used to parse XML
import requests #used to service API request

itemtypeid1 = 34
itemtypeid2 = 35
regionid = 10000002

webpage = requests.get('http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=%i&typeid=%i&regionlimit=%i' % (
itemtypeid1, itemtypeid2, regionid))

if webpage.status_code == 200:
    data = html.fromstring(webpage.content)
    for item in data.iter('type'):


        buy_dict = {node.tag: node.text for node in item.xpath("buy/*")}
        sell_dict = {node.tag: node.text for node in item.xpath("sell/*")}

        #Variables for output
        itemid = (item.get("id"))
        buymin = buy_dict['min']
        buymax = buy_dict['max']
        buymedian = buy_dict['median']
        buyvolume = buy_dict['volume']
        buyaverage = buy_dict['avg']

#Fail if api webpage unavaliable
else:
        print "Webpage unavaliable"
        Webpage.raise_for_status()


#############################################################################


import psycopg2

connection = psycopg2.connect(database='evemarketdata', user='postgres', password='black3car')

#open a cursor to perform DB operations
cursor = connection.cursor()

#create new table
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE arkonor (itemid integer primary key, min integer, max integer, median integer, volume integer, average integer);")

#Insert row data into DB table
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO arkonor (typeid, min, max, median, volume, average)
     VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""",
     ('itemid', 'buymin', 'buymax', 'buymedian', 'buyvolume', 'buyaverage'))


#Commits all changes does with cursor
#connection.commit()
```

results in

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "E:\Eve Spreadsheets\Python\PostgreConnect.py", line 49, in <module>

('itemid', 'buymin', 'buymax', 'buymedian', 'buyvolume', 'buyaverage'))

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: Just passing by and want to remind you that: in the execute statement of "INSERT", you are actually passing 6 strings to the query. You need to pass the value of your variables (i.e, without the quotation marks)

Answer (score 7):

You have 8 parameters in the query but provided only 6 fields in the tuple. The code should be:

```
#Insert row data into DB table
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO arkonor (typeid, min, max, median, volume, average)
     VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""",
     ('itemid', 'buymin', 'buymax', 'buymedian', 'buyvolume', 'buyaverage'))
```